# tinymce trims last space

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I am writing a module that change content. I use tinymce & i get all content using

```
var txt = editor.getContent({format: 'text'});
```

when i do my fixes, i get content via AJAX & put my content using

```
editor.setContent(results.text);
```

setContent erases all previous text & put new one but it puts cursor at the start of the line so i used smthg like this:

```
editor.selection.select(editor.getBody(), true);
editor.selection.collapse(false);
```

I need to add one space after setContent(results.text) .I need to put cursor after space, but it(tinymce) trims last space & put cursor at last symbol.

Can U advertise me what to do?

Comment: i use to press space bar which sends ajax.it simply do not ads/

Comment: Have you tried adding ' .' (a space followed by a dot), and then removing the last character (the dot)?

Comment: Myself facing the same issue.. I need to validate the content on key events and set the data. In this case if I setContent with space, tinymce ignores the space.